# How to use WCF service with raw messages?

Tags: wcf, message

I'm trying to use WCF service with raw messages.

1) WCF service code:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public static List<Person> CreateEmployees()
{
    List<Person> lstPersons = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Andrey", LastName = "Andreyev" },
        new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Sergey", LastName = "Sergeyev" }
    };

    return lstPersons;
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = TestService.RequestAction, ReplyAction = TestService.ReplyAction)]
    Message GetPersonById(Message id);
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public const String ReplyAction = "http://localhost:4249/Message_ReplyAction";
    public const String RequestAction = "http://localhost:4249/Message_RequestAction";

    public Message GetPersonById(Message id)
    {
        string firstName = Employees.CreateEmployees().First(e => e.Id == id.GetBody<int>()).FirstName;
        Message response = Message.CreateMessage(id.Version, ReplyAction, firstName);
        return response;
    }
}
```

2) Client code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient();
    String RequestAction = "http://localhost:4249/Message_RequestAction";
    int value = 1;
    Message request = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, RequestAction, value);
    Message reply = client.GetPersonById(request);
    string firstName = reply.GetBody<string>();

    Console.WriteLine(firstName);
    client.Close();
}
```

When I run the client with: int value = 1 everything works fine. But, when I use: int value = 2 I get the following error:

> *Error in line 1 position 276. Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Fault', namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'.*

At line:

```
string firstName = reply.GetBody<string>();
```

The service is started and I've added the service reference through "Add Service Reference..." in VS2008. I use .NET Framework 3.5.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Thank you in advance for help.

Goran

Comment: can you post up the full messages captured? you can get these using the wcf tester or mse service tester - its telling you theres been an error, and your code cant handle this client side.

Comment: If you mean on WCF Test Client, I can't use it because there's red icon with white exclamation mark and message in tool tip: "This operation is not supported in the WCF Test Client because it uses type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're getting a SOAP Fault. Try logging the message (either with Fiddler, with WCF Logging, or by just reading from Message.GetReaderAtBodyContents from the message you get from the server on the client-side), and see what the fault actually says. Make sure you turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults on the server side.

Comment: I've ran Fiddler and the client code, but nothing happened in Fiddler.

Comment: Also, I wrote this:             Message reply = client.GetPersonById(request);
            XmlDictionaryReader reader = reply.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
            string firstName = reply.GetBody<string>(); And reader is: reader = {Element, Name="Fault"}

Comment: What I mean is, after you do "XmlDictionaryReader reader = reply.GetReaderAtBodyContents();", take the entire XML from "reader" and log it to the console. What do you see? It should tell you exactly what happened on the server if the server has IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults turned on)

Comment: What does this "take the entire XML from "reader" and log it to the console" mean?

Comment: With this line of code: XmlDictionaryReader reader = reply.GetReaderAtBodyContents(); there's new error: "This message cannot support the operation because it has been read." at this line: string firstName = reply.GetBody<string>();

Comment: Remove the line "string firstName = reply.GetBody<string>()" for now. The error message is right, you can only read a message once. Read it with GetReaderAtBodyContents for now, just for debugging purposes.

Comment: I did it and there's the same message: "reader {Element, Name="Fault"} System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader {System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader}"

Comment: I don't understand why it's working with 1 and doesn't work with 2.

Comment: I've never worked with WCF that uses Message class. Why should we use Message class?